# How to use order by before group by in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, group-by, android-sqlite, min, having-clause

I want to combine information from two data table, `t1` and `t2`

t1:

```
ID TIME_ADD
 1 1620838960308
 2 1620879991077
 3 1620927396290
```

t2:

```
ID TIME_START    TIME_END      LEVEL
 1 1620837000611 1620840600621 0
 2 1620837000611 1620846000620 1
 3 1620837000611 1620851400622 0
 4 1620837000611 1620879262116 3
 5 1620837000611 1620881062117 2
 6 1620837000611 1620882862117 0
 7 1620923400574 1620923400577 2
 8 1620923400574 1620930600578 1
 ...
```

therefore, I have the query as following:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.LEVEL 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 
ON t2.TIME_START < t1.TIME_ADD AND t2.TIME_END >= t1.TIME_ADD 
WHERE t1.TIME_ADD >= '1620837000611' AND t1.TIME_ADD <= '1620882862117'
ORDER BY t1.TIME_ADD
GROUP BY t1.TIME_ADD
```

And expected result to be

```
ID TIME_ADD      LEVEL
 1 1620838960308 0
 2 1620879991077 2
```

However, the query above does not work, and it seems to be that I'm using `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` wrongly. Spent quite some time to try to find out a way, also looking into using `INNER JOIN` with `LIMIT`, but without success. So any support here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: GROUP BY must be written before ORDER BY.

Comment: but then i will get a wrong result

Comment: You will get your expected result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3ec41c5e330557281dd23f8bcf7728f6

Comment: umm, its weird, cause in android sqlite query it does not work

Comment: Why do you use GROUP BY if you don't want to do any aggregation?

Comment: thought that would be the way to get the first hit item if in order, what else would you suggest?

Comment: By first you mean the one with the least t2.ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause comes after the `GROUP BY` clause.

If you want 1 row for each distinct `TIME_ADD` of `t1` with the `LEVEL` of the row with the min `ID` of `t2`, you can do it with `HAVING MIN(t2.ID)`, which is a feature of SQLite (assuming there is no `ID` in `t2` with a `0` value):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.LEVEL 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 
ON t2.TIME_START < t1.TIME_ADD AND t2.TIME_END >= t1.TIME_ADD 
WHERE t1.TIME_ADD >= '1620837000611' AND t1.TIME_ADD <= '1620882862117'
GROUP BY t1.TIME_ADD
HAVING MIN(t2.ID)
ORDER BY t1.TIME_ADD;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=016dcfd249e0f7a625df3f25b12ab9d8).